# Implementing fraud-proof voting system using SimpleDB

Tags: amazon-simpledb

I'd like to implement a voting system with all data stored in Amazon SimpleDB. The frontend is also running on Amazon EC2. My main concern is cost of the service.

The voting system needs to be fraud-proof. That is, each visitor is only allowed one vote per election and there are no user accounts. I have considered storing a SimpleDB item for each vote along with the ip address it came from. Then I would only insert a new vote if there is no entry for that ip/election pair.

However, this sounds very expensive in terms of storage and processing. I would have to retrieve all votes to tally them up to display an up to date result.

The other option I have considered is storing the votes and only occasionally summing them up and caching the result. But this still requires me to store all of the votes.

What is your recommendation?

Comment: You're assuming each unique voter is locked to a unique IP, when this is typically a many-to-many (each voter could have multiple IPs, and each IP could represent multiple voters) relation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's address your main concern first, cost. Lets assume you have 1 000 000 votes in your system. Each vote is represented by one simpledb item and each item contains three attributes, a timestamp, the actual vote and a unique value identifying the user (I'll get to that part later).

Now, the [simpledb overview page](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) gives us a simple way of calculating the actual storage size of an item.

> Amazon SimpleDB measures the size of
> your billable data by adding the raw
> byte size of the data you upload + 45
> bytes of overhead for each item,
> attribute name and attribute-value
> pair.

Lets calculate with a bit of headroom in case you decide to include more data and let's say that each item/vote will cost you 300 bytes of storage. The total storage size for your data will then be ~286mb. Well within the free tier limit. Then there's the cost of inserting your items but that will probably be negligible. There's a cost associatied with tallying votes but as you've already suggesting caching can help alleviate this significantly.

I threw these numbers into the excellent [Amazon Simple Monthly Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html) service to get an approximate figure and got ~$4/month for 1GB storage, 1M puts, 250k gets and 100k selects. Now, in my experience it's very hard to approximate usage beforehand so you have to keep an eye on our usage as you go along. The usage reports provided by amazon contains detailed information about requests and you can use that to look at the effects of simulated real world usage of your app.

### Fraud proof

Now, as for the fraud-proof part. It's a bit hard for me to assess the level of fraud-prevention you're looking for but in any case you're simply not going to have a fraud-proof voting system without user accounts. Even if you have accounts you have to be extremely careful to avoid [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) so that malicious users won't exploit other users and their votes.

Limiting vote per IP has a number of problems.

- Some ISP:s aggressively reuses ip-addresses for their customers
- It's too easy to fake your IP using any of the large number of anonymization tools (proxys, vpn:s) that's flourished during the torrent era. Free "legit" tools such as [TOR](http://www.torproject.org/) can also be used.
- Many large organizations/governments/schools will send all of their users' traffic through a proxy or use NAT which means that only one user per organization will be able to cast their votes.

There's even a possibility of users have a different ip-address on each request(!)

> Speaking of sticky sessions, we were
> surprised to find that there are those
> rare few users whose IP addresses will
> change radically from request to
> request.
>
> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/

If you're truly serious about creating a fool-proof online voting system you'll have to look into user accounts with real world identity verification of some sort (ie sending verification codes via post to the users registered address).

And last, but not least. Regardless of the sofistication of your fraud prevention mechanism you have to perform regurlar auditing of your data to detect unexpected fraud scenarios early on.

Comment: Markus is spot on,  ut in the off chance you aren't trying to secure something like a political election and can deal with some fraudulent votes you could use a client cookie as one tier of protection from fraud, and ip addresses as another and partial IPs (first two segments) plus the agent string plus the vote cast as a last ditch effort to try and ID someone. That last segment is really broad, maybe just raise a red flag for a manual audit if you see a ton of matching votes using the last mechanism come in. Not fool proof, but hopefully decent.